# error while running makefile for opencl program

Tags: makefile, opencl

I have just started learning OpenCL.  I received the following error when I typed in `make` to compile the HelloCL program:

```
mkdir -p depends/x86_64
perl ../../../../../make/fastdep.pl -I. -I../../../../../include  -I../../../../../samples/opencl/SDKUtil/include --obj-suffix='.o' --obj-prefix='build/debug/x86_64//' HelloCL.cpp > depends/x86_64/HelloCL.depend
mkdir -p build/debug/x86_64/
Building build/debug/x86_64//HelloCL.o
g++  -Wpointer-arith   -Wfloat-equal -g3 -ffor-scope   -I  ../../../../../samples/opencl/SDKUtil/include -I  "/opt/AMDAPP/include"  -I  ../../../../../include  -o build/debug/x86_64//HelloCL.o -c  HelloCL.cpp
In file included from HelloCL.cpp:106:0:
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp: In function ‘cl_int cl::UnloadCompiler()’:
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp:1826:12: error: ‘::clUnloadCompiler’ has not been declared
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp: In member function ‘cl_int cl::CommandQueue::enqueueMarker(cl::Event*) const’:
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp:4842:13: error: ‘::clEnqueueMarker’ has not been declared
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp: In member function ‘cl_int cl::CommandQueue::enqueueWaitForEvents(const std::vector<cl::Event>&) const’:
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp:4849:13: error: ‘::clEnqueueWaitForEvents’ has not been declared
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp: In member function ‘cl_int cl::CommandQueue::enqueueBarrier() const’:          
/opt/AMDAPP/include/CL/cl.hpp:4985:13: error: ‘::clEnqueueBarrier’ has not been declared                      
make: *** [build/debug/x86_64//HelloCL.o] Error 1
```

Can someone help me understand the errors I am seeing, and suggest the corrections that need to be made?

Comment: What is the AMD APP SDK Version are you using? errors appears to be related to deprecated API's for OpenCL 1.1, Try running samples which does not use C++ for examples samples under opencl/cl/app do you still get an error ?

Comment: the version is 1.0, could you please tell me what I am supposed to do about these deprecated APIs?  thanks for the help...   and please do help....

Comment: I am able to run samples which doesn't contain c++ wrapper APIs.  Could you please tell me how to fix the above problem?  I typed in #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_0_APIS, but still I am getting the same errors.   please help....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cl.hpp you use is not adopted for the version of OpenCL your SDK supports. Try the [cl.hpp from the Khronos site](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/).

Comment: actually i am working on a system in which opencl has already been installed by a previous user, how can i make out the version the opencl version?

Comment: @user1456061 There are a number of calls to get info about current platform and device. See documentation for [clGetPlatformInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformInfo.html) and [clGetDeviceInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)

Comment: I typed in the clGetPlatformInfo function in main.c and compiled it too. But when executing only the vector addition o/p (in kernel) is displayed. Why is that so?                                         & I am still not able to compile the program written using c++ wraper,     I typed in #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_0_APIS, but still I am getting the same error as above.  please do help....

Comment: The o/p I got for querying version is this: ..........VERSION......... = b��  What does this stand for?        And when I ran it a second time the o/p was: ..........VERSION......... = �Q��   Please tell me why this is  happening......

Comment: @user1456061 From version to version developers of OpenCL introduce new methods and mark old as deprecated. That is, modern version of the OpenCL library does not some old methods and C++ wrapper excludes them when compiled against headers of this version. It appears to me that you use cl.hpp which is not properly updated to work with OpenCL 1.2 Unfortunately Khronos does not update their cl.hpp yet, so you have to download the recent AMD APP SDK and grab cl.hpp from there.

Answer (score 0):

I advise downloading latest AMD APP SDK from : http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx

And try running the samples again, this SDK supports: OpenCL 1.2, so you shouldn't see any issues.

Comment: Dont you think I will still have trouble with the deprecated APIs?